# Laravel Resource conditional fields

Tags: laravel, laravel-resource, laravel-response

In Laravel I'm generating serialized responses using resource classes. I have the following resources: JobOffer and Business. Here is JobOfferResource::toArray method

```
public function toArray(Request $request): array
{
    return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'title' => $this->title,
        ...
        'business' => new BusinessResource($this->whenLoaded('business')),
        ...
    ];
}
```

And here's BusinessResource::toArray

```
public function toArray(Request $request): array
{
    return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'name' => $this->name,
        'logo' => $this->logo,
        ...
    ];
}
```

What would be the best way to limit fields in JobOfferResource in collection case? For example

```
GET /api/v1/job_offer/{id}

{
    id: id,
    title: title,
    ...
    business: {
        id: business_id,
        name: name,
        address: address,
        logo: logo,
        ...
    }
}
```

But JobOfferCollection has limited fields for Business

```
GET /api/v1/job_offer

[
    {
        id: id,
        title: title,
        ...
        business: {
            name: name,
            address: address,
            logo: logo
        },
    },
    ...
]
```

So far I came up with several ways

1. Create new resources like \Short\JobOfferResource->\Short\BusinessResource and have limited fields there
2. Create JobOfferCollection resource and run over collection limiting those fields manually
3. Use Resource::additional method to add parameters, like

```
return JobResource::collection($jobOffer::all())->additional(['short' => true]);
```

```
public function toArray(Request $request): array
{
    return [
        'id' => $this->when(!$this->short, $this->id),
        'name' => $this->name,
        'address' => $this->address,
        'logo' => $this->logo,
        'field' => $this->when($this->short, $this->field),
    ];
}
```

4. Modify existing parent Resource class, as well as my classes as follows

```
protected bool $short = false;

public function setShort(bool $short): static
{
    $this->$short = $short;
    return $this;
}
```

```
public function toArray(Request $request): array
{
    return [
        'id' => $this->when(!$this->short, $this->id),
        'name' => $this->name,
        'address' => $this->address,
        'logo' => $this->logo,
        'field' => $this->when($this->short, $this->field),
    ];
}
```

```
public function toArray(Request $request): array
{
    return [
        ...
        'business' => new BusinessResource($this->whenLoaded('business'))->setShort($this->short),
        ...
    ];
}
```

What can I try next?